# Using the same ViewModel for a HTML and WPF view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, cross-platform

It it possible to use the same ViewModel for a View implemented in C# (WPF) and a View in HTML ?[image]

My goal is to be able to switch to a web View in the future, without rewriting everything.

Comment: Short answer: No. HTML is not compliant with .NET and vice versa. You may use a framework such as ASP.NET with Razor or Blazor to mix and match but that's another story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [ASP.NET Core Blazor framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Blazor allows you to mix C# code with HTML together, but it's not longer *.html format - the new format is called **razor**.